# Unable to Connect to Multiple Stack Exchange Sites

Tags: support, bug

It may just be me, but I tried this on my phone as well. I am receiving 503 errors on every other attempt to connect to any Stack Exchange site, specifically StackOverflow in the picture below. I am honestly not sure how I managed to connect here without receiving the error, but it is happening for me on the meta site as well. For some reason, in the picture below it wasn't a page returned from the server, but from Chrome, but I have also received the error page from the server as well.

[image: 503 error]

Comment: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1006577877947682822

Comment: We're investigating right now, it looks like an issue with a build.

Comment: StackOverflow Teams site experiencing problems as well.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate I guess: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369352/stackoverflow-503-errors-while-browsing

Comment: @geisterfurz007 That one at Meta SO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue has been resolved - a build went out with some bad async code that was causing a crash of a low-level IIS process.